# base64 decode command linux cli command

Tags: bash, base64, decode

May I ask besides on echoing, is there is a way where I can cat a file and retrieve the string then use it to decode via `base64`?

This command works

```
echo "dctyGqLcE5s+D3gzO9pxQo8C+YABV7SBbfn2jamVzVc=" | base64 --decode > out.txt
```

I tried to place the string on text file named to file.text and replace echo to cat, but seems failed

```
echo "`cat file.txt`" | base64 --decode > out.txt
```

Error Message:

> base64: invalid input

Comment: The first command does not work.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Remove the redirect and it works `echo "A123mkjfjfkbmtohgdsdjfksdoutoerndnfjhaisd="  | base64 -d`

Comment: `echo "dctyGqLcE5s+D3gzO9pxQo8C+YABV7SBbfn2jamVzVc=" > new_file.txt`, then `base64 --decode new_file.txt`. IT SHOULD WORK

Comment: yes this worked out!

Answer (score 3):

Usage:

`man base64`

```sh
base64 file.txt > encoded.txt # to encode
base64 -d encoded.txt > decoded.txt  # to decode
```

You can also use

```
cat file.txt | base64 # to encode
cat encoded.txt | base64 -d # to decode
```

**Note**:

If you get `base64: INVALID INPUT` error, that means your input file is not a base64 encoded file( it can not be decoded with base64). Example try to decode your text file.

```sh
base64 -d file.txt
```

Output:

```
base64: invalid input
```

Comment: still getting same error, my goal is to decode the string that is saved from a file

Comment: @Lagot If you get INVALID INPUT error, then it means your input file is not a base64 encoded file

Comment: @Lagot what is the content of your file. please attack the text file. Otherwise the problem is with your text file. If it can not be decoded with base64, it raises the error `invalid input`

Comment: Sorry I'm bit slow to understand it, does it mean the INPUT text that is working fine when decoding via echo is the only way?

Comment: @Lagot What is the content of your text file? attach it on github or some place. Thats the only way I can help you

Comment: Please try the 1st command I provided above, the string worked fine when I echo it.
However if I try to place in file then do the cat command, I ended up with an error

Comment: @Lagot did you get something like this when you run the first command? `u�r����>x3;�qB���W��m������W`

Comment: yes, that is the expected result on the out.txt which is what we need to generate

Comment: Well when you put it into a file and try to decode it, it doesn't work because the command only outputs the result if its decodable. Some of the strings are not readable. Thus decode on file only works if the output is readable

Comment: Here try this one. try decoding this stirng `SGVsbG8gV29ybGQK`. first with echo, then by putting it in a file. IT SHOULD WORK

Comment: it both work and showed Hello World. I think the problem is on the string we are using. We did not encode it, that was provided by the cloud kms provider which might have some restriction on decoding using cat.

Comment: @Lagot , yes. You made an error when copying your string to a file. Try `echo "dctyGqLcE5s+D3gzO9pxQo8C+YABV7SBbfn2jamVzVc=" > new_file.txt`, then try decoding it. IT SHOULD WORK

Comment: Your file may contain DOS line endings: `0x0d` `0x0a` which causes the base64 decode error. Please apply `dos2unix` on your input file or just say `tr -d "\r" < file.txt | base64 -d`.